# Run specific standalone ant target from Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I've got the following plugin defined in my POM in an attempt to deploy the maven produced .war file either on our test or production tomcat server:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <target name="test-deploy">
      <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>
        <deploy 
          path="/${project.name}" 
          url="http://test-server:8080/manager/text" 
          username="user" 
          password="pass"
          war="file:${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}" 
          update="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="prod-deploy">
      <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>
        <deploy 
          path="/${project.name}" 
          url="http://prod-server:8080/manager/text" 
          username="user" 
          password="pass"
          war="file:${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}" 
          update="true"/>
    </target>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ant</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

From reading the [Maven AntRun Plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) it looks like I should be able to add a target name (as I've done), but I'm not sure how to invoke a specific target.  The `web-deploy` target is the only target run even if I try to invoke only the `test-deploy` target with:

```
mvn antrun:run -Dtarget=test-deploy
```

How do I specify which ant target I'd like to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

I suggest using [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to split the maven tasks and calling them with maven's ability to trigger profiles based on conditions or command line parameters.
It means that each profile will declare its own **maven-antrun-plugin**, but will give you the flexibility to call them individually.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your answer.  I'll do as you suggest and hopefully report back with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eldad AK's answer, here is a simple working solution using maven profiles to customize the ant target run for that profile:

```
        ...
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7</version>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>
                <echo message="Deploying to ${tomcat.deploy.url}"/>
                <deploy 
                  path="/${project.name}" 
                  url="${tomcat.deploy.url}" 
                  username="${tomcat.deploy.username}" 
                  password="${tomcat.deploy.password}"
                  war="file:${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}" 
                  update="true"/>
            </target>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ant</artifactId>
              <version>8.0.14</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
          <tomcat.deploy.url>http://test-server:8080/manager/text</tomcat.deploy.url>
          <tomcat.deploy.username>user</tomcat.deploy.username>
          <tomcat.deploy.password>pass</tomcat.deploy.password>
        </properties>
      </profile>
      <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
          <tomcat.deploy.url>http://prod-server:8080/manager/text</tomcat.deploy.url>
          <tomcat.deploy.username>user</tomcat.deploy.username>
          <tomcat.deploy.password>pass</tomcat.deploy.password>
        </properties>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
```

To deploy to test or prod, just choose the appropriate profile:

```
> mvn -Pprod antrun:run

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ExampleApplication 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default-cli) @ ExampleApplication ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Deploying to http://prod-server:8080/manager/text
   [deploy] OK - Deployed application at context path /ExampleApplication
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```